# Assign Azure BLOB Container Access to Users

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to create 500 Azure BLOB Containers for users to store their data on it.

Each user should have Contributor access to only their respective Container and not able to access other container in the same Storage account.

I have tested it manually with few users/containers by allowing BLOB contributor access at container level and users were not able to access other containers.

How can I do the same for 500 users using CLI/script, especially assigning Contributor access at container to the respective user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options how to complete your task: Powershell, AzureCLI, REST API, SDK.
Here is an example how to create Azure Storage Container and give contributor access:

```
az storage container create --account-name <storage-account> --name <container>  --auth-mode login
az role assignment create --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" --assignee <email> --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container>"
```

Additionally you will need to have user's email list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli#create-a-container

Comment: Anyway to assign role to the container in bulk if I have the users and containers available ? Or I need to run the command for each and every user.

Comment: Wrap these commands in a powershell script

Comment: @SteveB, please provide any reference so I can test it out. Thanks

Comment: You can add user emails into csv file, wrap above az cli commands in a powershell script.
Powershell could read from csv
with command $csv = Import-Csv C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv

and then iterate in for each
$csv.Email| ForEach-Object {
    # In here, we do whatever want to the 'cell' that's currently in the pipeline
    # For now, let's just output it.
    $_
}

Comment: Andriy's comment is exactly what I have in mind. It's a common pattern in powershell. Maybe you should invest some times to learn PowerShell. It's quite easy to learn and I strongly feel it's a prerequisite of most Microsoft product integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndriyBilous, the PowerShell script is now working as expected.
And yes I'm currently at beginner level for scripting.